# Python: __setattr__ operator overloading

Tags: python, operator-overloading

I have made a Poly class which does different overload operations on polynomials.

If an attempt is made to add new attributes to a polynomial object (by defining a new attribute or rebinding an existing attribute), I want to raise an AssertionError.

How would I do that in **setattr**?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the **slots** function as well - It will raise a attribute error

```
class Test(object):
    __slots__ = ['var']
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.var = n

y = Test(1)
print y.var
y.var = 2
print y.var
y.z = 4    
print y.z
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class CONST(object):
    FOO = 1234

    def __setattr__(self, *_):
        raise AssertionError

const = CONST()
print const.FOO    # 1234
const.FOO = 4321   # AttributeError
```

is this what u nedd?